# What is the technique called in which you return a never ending http response to keep returning lines of javascript for dynamic update effect?

Tags: web-development, terminology

There is a technique in which you don't end the response and this allows you to send content to the client in chunks like pieces of javascript or maybe xml document that can be parsed on the client side and give an effect of updating something in real time instead of polling the server again and again.

Was there such a technique or am I dreaming?
Do you have reference to an online article explaining this?

Comment: its called [Long Polling][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code

Comment: It's not long polling. In long polling, there is a long timeout on a request. The request/response isn't "never ending" at all.

Comment: It is called Http Streaming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're definitely describing [push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), and it sounds like you're describing what's called "pushlet" on Wikipedia. I've heard of this technique, but I wasn't aware of its name until just now. It appears this name is more widespread, with [a website dedicated to explaining how to use pushlets](http://www.pushlets.com/).